# Run Scala 2.9.0 application on IntellijIdea 10

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I run my Scala hello world application, like

```
package pack

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
```

on Idea 10.0.3, I get compile errors

> 'App' to
>   D:\prog\java2\scala3\out\production\scala3\pack\App.class
>   (The filename, directory name, or
>   volume label syntax is incorrect)
>
> 'App' to
>   D:\prog\java2\scala3\out\production\scala3\pack\App$.class
>   (The filename, directory name, or
>   volume label syntax is incorrect)

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Keep an eye on the official forum for the IDEA Scala Plugin, this question has been answered over there: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/scala

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an Intellij bug.  See bug [SCL-3185](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-3185) in the jetbrains tracking for pointers to release candidate code fixing it.

Comment: Supposedly this should be fixed in 10.5 release (but I haven't tried it yet)?

Comment: @Toland - It is indeed fixed in the IDEA 10.5 RC release candidate.  I tried it yesterday.  It does also require getting a nightly build of the plugin, as noted in the bug report comments.